# Excel Scalability and Speed Issues (VBA, Array and Comboboxes)

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, combobox

**Context**

There are two excel.workbooks in the same location: database and dashboards. Whereas database.workbook has as many tabs as clients I manage, dashboard.workbook has as many tabs as reports are required.

Navigation across report's (dashboard.worksheets) it's pretty simple. On each report there's a combobox that contains every dashboard.worksheets' names. Selecting any report on that combobox hides the current worksheet/report and open the desired one.

In each tab/report there is a second combobox that allows you to select a client, populating the report with the selected client's data.

**The report**

The information in the database looks like this: 
Date|Device|Group|Subgroup|metric1|metric2|metric3|etc.

The information displayed in the report (in the one I'm having issues with) looks like this:
Group|metric1|2|3|...

**The issues**

**1)** Currently the group is displayed like this:

```html
=IFERROR(LOOKUP(2,1/(COUNTIF($C$17:C18,IF($C$8="Goldsmiths",Client1_GroupName,IF($C$8="Client2",Client2_GroupName,IF($C$8="Client3",Client3_GroupName,IF($C$8="Client4",Client4_GroupName)))))=0),IF($C$8="Client1",Client1_GroupName,IF($C$8="Client2",Client2_GroupName,IF($C$8="Client3",Z2,Client3_GroupName($C$8="Client4",Client4_GroupName))))),"")
```

- The combobox prints its value into Range("C8"). Through a nested ifs structure the formula identifies the client and then pulls a unique list of groups from the selected client tab (from database.workbook).
- One issue is that it is very messy and hard to escalate (the more clients I get, its complexity growth exponentially). I bet there are easiest ways to do it (maybe VBA?).
- It can be quite slow, the more "groups" we get and more days recorded into the database, more slow it will get.

**2)** Pulling the data
Most of the data to pull can be done through array formulas like this one:

```html
={SUM((Client1_GroupName=C20)*Metric1)}
```

- It sums all the Metric1 for the *group* matching C20,C21,22,23 (in that c20:xx range we have the first formula pulling the Group list.
- I haven't added the nested ifs yet. It's going to be a pain to do it across 5 more columns. Again very hard to escalate.
- This can be terribly slow. It comes a point that changing client means waiting 2 or 3 minutes to process the array.

**Conclusions**

I guess what I'm seeking is some advice on how to face this issues, which essentially are: scalability and speed.

Comment: Is the issue just in your reports? Why don't you try downloading Power BI (free) and have a play

Comment: Never heard about it before tbh. It looks quite good.
That said, if anyone comes across a problem like this. I've come with what it seems a solution (actually a colleague of mine did). Instead of using array formulas we're using INDIRECT which also allows to have the client as a variable.